# How can I remap the power key on a MacBook Air?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to make a program that allows more flexibility in remapping keys. All of the keys are fine so far except for the power key. Is there a way to remap the location of the key itself or even just possibly disable it through terminal or applescript?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately not.

It was possible a few years ago with the tool Karabiner. However, starting with OS X 10.9 the feature was removed. See: [Google: pqrs karabiner power-button](https://www.google.de/#q=pqrs+karabiner+power-button)